# How to config linux kernel's compile flag?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm working with Xilinx petalinux.

When i make a module, which uses float point type, trigger a mistake.

Mistake as below:

```
error: ‘-mgeneral-regs-only’ is incompatible with floating-point code
```

I find ‘-mgeneral-regs-only’ define in "arch/arm64/Makefile", and no config option to control it. How can i fix this problem?

Please help.

Comment: Better to correct your source code.

Comment: Yes, after correct code, I want to know the principle.

Comment: You are confused. If you did correct your source code, what "principle" do you want to understand? Learn more about integer overflow and other kind of undefined behavior.